# How to work out the total cost of an item using a Scanner?

Tags: java

I need to write a program that will allow the user to type in the name of an item followed
by a space and then the cost of the item. The user must continually type in item 
names and costs. The program will terminate when the user enters "STOP" as input.
The program must determine the total cost of all the items entered.

Sample Input: 
coke 12.50
pie 11.65
fanta 12.00
coffee 13.78
STOP

Sample Output:
Total Cost: R49.93

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

String details = "";
        double total_cost = 0;

        while(!details.equals("STOP")){
            details = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item cost and name");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(details);
            while(sc.hasNextDouble()){
                double price = sc.nextDouble();
                total_cost = total_cost + price;
                System.out.println("Total Cost: R" + total_cost);
```

However my code outputs nothing except a build successful`enter code here. What am I doing wrong? Excuse the lack of polish in my question I am new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: please edit your question to add what your code currently does and why this is not the desired behavior

Comment: "does not work" is a lousy description of your problem, explain why it doesn't work. Does it crash or do you get the wrong result or...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to match `STOP` with the next token from the input, not with the whole of input. Also, as per your requirement, the input should be outside the loop. Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String details = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item cost and name");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(details);
        double total_cost = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext() && !sc.next().equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
            if (sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                double price = sc.nextDouble();
                total_cost = total_cost + price;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Total Cost: R" + total_cost);
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[image]

```
Total Cost: R49.93
```

**[Update]**

If you want to process individual entries e.g. `coke 12.50` and then `pie 11.65` and so on, you can do it as follows:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double total_cost = 0;
        String details;
        do {
            details = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter item cost and name");
            String[] tokens = details.split("\\s+");
            if (tokens.length >= 2) {
                try {
                    double price = Double.parseDouble(tokens[1]);
                    total_cost = total_cost + price;
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Wrong input");
                }
            }
        } while (!details.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP"));
        System.out.println("Total Cost: R" + total_cost);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there no way to edit it that a separate JOptionPane is presented for every item and cost?

Comment: @GenericJudd - You're most welcome. I've added an update to do it this way as well. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.